# Office Excel 2011 for Mac : when exporting an excel sheet to csv, around 25000 empty csv lines get added

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export, microsoft-excel-2011

so when saving as windows csv and press save i get the actual data:

`1,1,2,`
then i get around 25'000 lines:

```
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
....
```

when i do the same with libre office i get only the data, no empty rows

how can I get the same in microsoft office 2011? that is, no empty rows